# Шифрование методом Виженера со сдвигом С++

Tags: c++, шифрование

Очень мало смыслю в программировании, задали написать на с++ шифрование Виженера на русском и со сдвигом алфавита. С горем пополам написал и надергал код, но что-то не сходится с примером. При сдвиге n=3, слове тритемиус и ключе - крыса, шифр должен быть - Ы Я А Б Е Х Ш Н А. У меня же - м т э у а м т э у. Не пойму, что не так.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string key = ""; //Строка - ключ ;
    string key_on_s = "";
    string A = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя ";
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int shift = 0;

    int n;
    cout << "Введите сдвиг таблицы шифрования\n";
    cin >> n;
    char arr[34][34];

    //формирование алфавита

    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 34; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0) {
                arr[i][j] = A[j];
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                arr[i][j] = A[(j + n) % 34];
            }
            if (i > 1) {
                shift = j + i + n - 1;
                if (shift >= 34) shift = shift % 34;
                arr[i][j] = A[shift];

            }
            cout << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    string result = ""; //Строка - результат
    bool flag;
    int x = 0, y = 0; //Координаты нового символа из таблицы Виженера
    cout << "Ввести слово для шифрования вручную или прочитать из файла?\n 1-вручную 2-из файла\n";
    int v;
    cin >> v;
    string s; //Строка считанная из файла
    if (v == 1) {
        cout << "Введите слово для шифрования \n";
        cin >> s;
    }
    else {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");//Чтение файла

        ifstream in("Test.txt");
        getline(in, s);
        cout << "Текст файла: \n" << s << endl;
        in.close();
    }
    cout << "Введите ключ\n";
    cin >> key;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        key_on_s += key[i % key.length()];
    }
    cout << key_on_s << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        int l = 0;
        flag = false;
        while ((l < 34) && (flag == false))
        {
            //Если символ найден
            if (key_on_s[i] == arr[0][l])
            {
                //Запоминаем в х номер столбца
                x = l;
                flag = true;
            }
            l++;
        }
        while ((l < 34) && (flag == false))
        {
            if (key_on_s[i] == arr[l][0])
            {
                //Запоминаем в у номер строки
                y = l;
                flag = true;
            }
            l++;
        }
        result += arr[x][y];
    }
    cout << "Вывести результат на экран или записать в файл?\n 1- на экран 2- в файл\n";
    int v1;
    cin >> v1;
    if (v1 == 1) {
        cout << result<<endl;
    }
    if (v1==2){
        ofstream f("crypro.txt");
        f << result << " ";
        f.close();
    }
    system("pause");
  
}
```

Comment: Что такое сдвиг n? (это число, которое по модулю 33 добавляется к символу ключа и и далее индексирует строку в квадрате Вижинера?)

Comment: сдвиг n - это число, на которое сдвигаются элементы второй строки матрицы из алфавитов, следующие строки имеют сдвиг n+1, n+2 и т.д.

Comment: А первая (с индексом 0) строка вообще вообще не сдвигается?

Comment: Да первая не сдвигается, вторая на n, далее на n+1 ...

Comment: У нас же условие для i, j==1, i==0 - A[j+n]=A[4]; j==2, i==0 - A[j+n]=A[5]

Comment: Вы путаете i и j

Comment: Не совсем Вас понимаю. У буквы А индекс j (A[j]) Разве нет? Да и при компиляции у меня в этой части всё нормально. Проблема с самим шифрованием, по крайней мере, мне так кажется...

Answer (score 1):

Я попробовал разобраться в вашей задаче, проведя анализ шифрования текста `ТРИТЕМИУС` ключем `крыса` с получением результата `ЫЯАБЕХшнА` (маленькими буквами выделил несоответствие (у меня получилось, что д.б. `ЧК`)) в соответствием с [описаниями в викепедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Также сразу замечу, что у вас в коде есть явная ошибочка -- шифруете не текст, а сам ключ (это о вашем вопросе *`"У меня же - м т э у а м т э у"`*).

Собственно, я попытался восстановить квадрат Виженера, по алфавитам, которые должны соответствовать буквам `КРЫСА` (5 строк), чтобы из `тритемиус` получать `ыяабехшна` (большими сделаны буквы, которые используются в преобразованиях).

Вот что получилось:

```
ТРИТЕМИУС
крысакрыс
   |
   V
ЫЯАБЕХшнА
      ЧК

А  абвгдЕёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя  (5)
б   абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя                                  
в  абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя 
г  бвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя а
д  вгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя аб
е  гдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абв
ё  деёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвг
ж  еёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгд
з  ёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгде
и  жзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеё
й  зийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёж

   абвгдеёжзийклМнопрсТуфхцчшщъыьэюя                                   
К  ийклмнопрстуфХцчшщъЫьэюя абвгдеёжз (1 Т->Ы, 6 М->Х)

л  йклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзи
м  клмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзий
н  лмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийк
о  мнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийкл
п  нопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклм

   абвгдеёжзийклмнопРстуфхцчшщъыьэюя 
Р  опрстуфхцчшщъыьэюЯ абвгдеёжзийклмн (2 Р->Я, 7 И->Ч (ш))
   абвгдеёжзийклмнопрсТуфхцчшщъыьэюя 
С  прстуфхцчшщъыьэюя аБвгдеёжзийклмно (4 Т->Б, 9 С->А)

т  рстуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмноп
у  стуфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмнопр
ф  туфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмнопрс
х  уфхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмнопрст
ц  фхцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмнопрсту
ч  хцчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуф
ш  цчшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфх
щ  чшщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхц
ъ  шщъыьэюя абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцч

   абвгдеёжзИйклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя 
Ы  шщъыьэюя Абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцч (3 И->А, 8 У->К (н))
```

Теперь, результаты анализа.

Похоже, что в задачу вкрались ошибки. По крайней мере сдвига на 3 я так и не увидел. Похоже, что в первой строке есть сдвиг на 1 вправо, который далее меняется на сдвиг на 1 влево,  а также обратите внимание, что строки для букв ключа `Ъ` и `Ы` должны совпадать, чтобы хоть как-то сохранить алгоритм сдвига на 1 от строки к строке.